# print group in R by condition

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr, data.table

Say, I have data

```
data=structure(list(x1 = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L), .Label = c("q", 
"r", "w"), class = "factor"), x2 = structure(c(2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L
), .Label = c("e", "w"), class = "factor"), x3 = structure(c(1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L), .Label = c("e", "q", "r"), class = "factor"), var = c(34L, 
35L, 34L, 34L, 34L, 34L, 35L, 34L, 34L, 34L, 34L, 35L, 34L, 34L, 
34L, 34L, 34L, 34L, 34L, 34L), act = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L)), .Names = c("x1", 
"x2", "x3", "var", "act"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-20L))
```

by columns `x1`, `x2`, `x3` we have three groups

```
q   w   e
w   e   r
r   e   q
```

I must print only those groups which for `act` column have only 1 value.
In this case,  only `w e r` group has by `act` column both 0 and 1 value, and
another group `q w e` and `r e q` has only 1 by `act` column, so I need to print it.
How to do it?

Expected output

```
x1  x2  x3
q   w   e
r   e   q
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
library(dplyr)
data %>% distinct(x1,x2,x3, .keep_all = TRUE) %>% 
         filter(act==1) %>% select(-var,-act)

  x1 x2 x3
1  q  w  e
2  r  e  q

data %>% distinct(x1,x2,x3, .keep_all = TRUE) %>% 
         filter(act==1) %>% select(-var,-act) %>%
         filter(x1=='r',x2=='e',x3=='q')

  x1 x2 x3
1  r  e  q


#OR 
data %>% filter(x1=='r',x2=='e',x3=='q')
```

Comment: Please, review your answer. As given, it just reproduces the expected result _by chance_. If the order of rows in the `w e r` group is changed so that a row with `act == 1` comes first, your code will fail.

Comment: @Uwe any answer in SO for R address the OP case and data structure provided in the question. Moreover, any R code is designed for a specific data structure.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly, the OP has requested to extract/print only those groups which contain only the value `1` in the `act` column.

This can be achieved using the `all()` function.

#### data.table

```
library(data.table)
setDT(data)[, which(all(act == 1L)), by = .(x1, x2, x3)][, -"V1"]
```

> ```
>    x1 x2 x3
> 1:  q  w  e
> 2:  r  e  q
> ```

#### dplyr

```
library(dplyr)
data %>% 
  group_by(x1, x2, x3) %>% 
  filter(all(act == 1L)) %>% 
  distinct(x1, x2, x3)
```

> ```
> # A tibble: 2 x 3
> # Groups:   x1, x2, x3 [2]
>   x1    x2    x3   
>   <fct> <fct> <fct>
> 1 q     w     e    
> 2 r     e     q
> ```

#### Data

In addition to the dataset `data` provided by the OP I have tested my answer with a second dataset which contains an additional group and where the rows in the `w e r` group are ordered differently.

```
data2 <- data.table::fread(
" x1 x2 x3 var act
  a  b  c  33   0
  a  b  c  33   0
  q  w  e  34   1
  q  w  e  35   1
  w  e  r  34   1
  w  e  r  35   1
  w  e  r  34   0
  w  e  r  35   0
  r  e  q  34   1
  r  e  q  34   1
", data.table = FALSE)
```